# Настройка зависимости ширины от высоты и наоборот в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gui

События происходят в самом главное элементе, в окне, а именно

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=ActualWidth}"  
Width="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=ActualHeight}"
```

Цель, уменьшаю ширину, уменьшается и высота. В чем тут проблема?

Comment: Пытался это - не вышло.
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}" 
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не смотрел, что за параметр ActualHeight. Студии нет, проверить не могу. По идее

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=Width}"
```

должно стоять в самой верхней иерархии, в результате значение высоты элемента= значению ширины (т.е. будет квадрат). В книге Макдоналда есть примеры со связкой.